# Calcium hydroxide questions (as it relates to corn and nixtamalization)

Tags: ph

Please pardon my chemistry ignorance! I actually have done a lot research on these specific topics, but can't find anything definitive--anywhere!

1. When adding calcium hydroxide to water and corn for [nixtamalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixtamalization), does the heat of the water have any effect on the "activation" of the calcium hydroxide (specific for this process)? How so?

1a. Specifically, what causes the change in water color (from clear to yellow)?

2. Does the ratio of calcium hydroxide to water have any effect on the process, or only calcium hydroxide to volume of material (i.e. corn)? Can you change the pH levels in water alone, with the more or less cal you add to the water? This may be obvious, but not to a non-chemist.
3. Since the solubility of calcium hydroxide decreases with increasing temperature, how does this affect the nixtamalization process?

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert in food processing, so just some general chemistry point of view:

- Higher water temperature increases speed of all chemical reactions. The typical increase is in the range 2-4 times by every $\pu{10^{\circ}C}.$. The reason behind it is that molecules at higher temperature move in average faster, have higher energy and more easily overcome the energetic barrier for the reaction to happen.
- The corn seeds are yellow. The process partially dissolves surface layers and the dye dissolves partially in water. Additionally, the color can be partially caused by oxidation of dissolved organic matter.
- There must be enough calcium hydroxide to form saturated solution, and to keep saturated solution during processing. This makes pH more or less constant, with extra hydroxide not having effect on this. BUT - with too low solution to corn ratio, solution can be partials exhausted, with additional calcium hydroxide eventually not readily supplied by dissolving.
- Effect of decreased solubility is much weaker than effect of increased reaction rate at higher temperature.